# How can I insert values as a distinct column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of about 50k records. It looks something like this:

```
Animal | Name | Color | Legs
Cat    |George| Black | 4
Cat    | Bob  | Brown | 4
Cat    | Dil  | Brown | 4
Bird   | Irv  | Green | 2
Bird   | Van  | Red   | 2
```

etc.

I want to only insert Cat once and Bird only once and so on. The Name / Color / Legs etc. should be the first value it finds.

This table has 10 columns and 50k rows.

I tried `insert into MyNewTable Select Distinct * From MyAnimalTable`, but that didn't work. I also tried `group by`, but did not work either.

Comment: *The Name / Color / Legs etc. should be the first value it finds.* ... first in accordance to which field?

Comment: There's no "first" here. How to chose which cat to insert?

Comment: Must the name, color and legs be consistent (i.e. George/Black or Bob/Brown or Dil/Brown are allowed, but not George/Brown, Bob/Black, Dil/Black) or not?

Comment: @Giorgos @ Jarlh Doesn't matter, really.

Comment: @Thorsten Doen't matter.

Comment: Okay, strange new table data then :-) Then Manoj Kumar's answer should be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use group by only on animal name and select the rest of the column from Max() to get the first finding.

```
insert into MyNewTable 
Select MAT.Animal,max(MAT.Name),max(MAT.Color),max(MAT.Legs)
From MyAnimalTable MAT GROUP BY MAT.Animal
```

Comment: Thank you Is Mat.etc really necessary?

Comment: Not at all, but its good to have table aliases for good understanding of tables which we are refereeing at many times in single query.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to number the rows per animal and only keep the ones numbered 1.

```
insert into mynewtable (animal, name, color, legs)
select animal, name, color, legs
from
(
  select 
    animal, name, color, legs,
    row_number() over (partition by animal order by animal) as rn
  from myanimaltable a
) numbered
where rn = 1;
```

(This numbers the records per animal arbitrarily. So you get the first record per animal "the DBMS finds". If you want any certain order, you'd have to specify this after the partition clause.)

Comment: @Prdp: Thank you for this helpful comment.

Comment: The code should read:
`row_number() over (partition by animal order by [order column]) as rn`

The [order column] should be the column by which you want to decide which row is the first.

Comment: @Sean Pearce: Ah, okay, I thought the `order by` clause was optional. As the OP is interested only in the first values found by the DBMS, i.e. with no specific order, I thought I could simply not specify any order. I'll update. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you're welcome. The order by is not optional and you must order by a column. Windowed functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions. Try `(partition by animal order by animal)` for an arbitrary row.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - How would except someone to point out your syntax mistakes you should be knowing that

Comment: @Sean Pearce: Thank you again. Not allowing constants in the order by clause is SQL Server specific. Well, I guess I'll have to update again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT A.Animal
    ,B.NAME
    ,C.color
    ,A.Legs
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Animal
        ,Legs
    FROM tablename
    ) A
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT NAME
    FROM tablename
    ) B
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Color
    FROM tablename
    ) C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
INSERT INTO MYNEWTABLE 
select  Animal,Name,Color,legs from
(select distinct Animal,Name,Color,legs,dense_rank() over(partition by animal)
as rnk from table) AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best simple solution for your query**

```
select 
Animal,
(select top 1 name from MyAnimalTable where animal=T.animal)  Name,
(select top 1 Color from MyAnimalTable where animal=T.animal) Color,
(select top 1 Legs from MyAnimalTable where animal=T.animal)  Legs
from MyAnimalTable T group by Animal
```